# Do I need to create a new itunes account?

Tags: iphone, itunes

I have an apple account to submit apps. I had recently submitted an app that was only songs. So, it was rejected by the apple developer team. They said that I need to submit to itunes. But, I am lost here, can I use the same id for this? Do I need to create an itunes account to submit my songs? I just don't know what to do..

thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Stack Overflow is the right place to ask.

However I would suggest checking out the [iTunes Partner Program](http://www.apple.com/itunes/sellcontent/).